# Svelte - The text inside my button does not change

Tags: javascript, html, svelte, svelte-3, svelte-component

### The situation is the following:

I have a multiple buttons that execute diferent async funtions.

All of them are progress buttons

What I want is that when the button is press, the label change indicating the state of the functionality (name of the funtionality, loading, done or error if is need it)

Everything works ok but the text do not change

**Note:** For now I have not implemented all four functions but with one should work

here are the components.

**Component 1 - Container**

```
<script>
  import Button from '../components/Button.svelte'
  import { cubiqSetUp } from '../../../store/store.js'
  import { fly } from 'svelte/transition'
  import URLS from '../../../api/endpoints.js'

  let loadingEffect = false
  let ButtonText = null
  async function calibrate(current) {
    console.log(current.detail)
    loadingEffect = true
    ButtonText = 'CARGANDO...'
    console.log(ButtonText)
    let { calibrateURL } = await URLS()
    await fetch(calibrateURL)
      .then(response => {
        loadingEffect = false
        ButtonText = 'LISTO'
        response.json()
        setTimeout(() => {
          ButtonText = current.detail
        }, 1500)
      })
      .catch(error => {
        ButtonText = 'ERROR'
        loadingEffect = false
        setTimeout(() => {
          ButtonText = current.detail
        }, 1500)
      })
  }
</script>

<div class="Buttons">
  <div class="Buttons-container">
    <Button
      on:active={() => console.log('Pending')}
      {loadingEffect}
      ButtonText="CUBICAR" />
    <Button
      on:active={calibrate}
      {loadingEffect}
      ButtonText="CALIBRAR"
      delay={400} />
    {#if $cubiqSetUp.print_info === 'true' && $cubiqSetUp.OCR === 'true'}
      <Button ButtonText="IMPRIMIR" delay={800} />
    {:else if $cubiqSetUp.print_info === 'true'}
      <Button ButtonText="GUARDAR" delay={800} />
      <Button ButtonText="IMPRIMIR" delay={1200} />
    {:else if $cubiqSetUp.OCR === 'true'}
      <!-- No additional buttons -->
    {:else}
      <Button ButtonText="GUARDAR" delay={800} />
    {/if}
  </div>
</div>
```

**Component 1 - Button**

```
<script>
  import { fly } from 'svelte/transition'
  import { createEventDispatcher } from 'svelte'

  const dispatch = createEventDispatcher()

  export let ButtonText = ''
  export let delay = 200
  export let loadingEffect = false
</script>

<div
  transition:fly={{ delay, y: 200, duration: 2000 }}
  on:click={() => dispatch('active', ButtonText)}
  class="progress-btn {loadingEffect ? 'active' : ''}">
  <div class="btn">{ButtonText}</div>
  <div class="progress" />
</div>
```

I'll appreciate if you guys give it a look

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming your question relates specifically to the `CALIBRAR` button since it's the only one actually triggering a full action/response cycle.

I don't know why you expect your button text to update when you set it to a predefined value:

```js
<Button
  on:active={calibrate}
  {loadingEffect}
  ButtonText="CALIBRAR"
  delay={400} />
```

The `ButtonText` in your component invocation above is a **prop name** and is not connected at all to the `ButtonText` variable you define in the `<script>` section. You have to do this explicitly:

```js
<Button
  on:active={calibrate}
  {loadingEffect}
  ButtonText={ButtonText}
  delay={400} />
```

or, since the prop name and variable name are the same, you can use the shorthand:

```js
<Button
  on:active={calibrate}
  {loadingEffect}
  {ButtonText}
  delay={400} />
```

You also have to update your script section to properly initialize your `ButtonText` variable since it is now used to set your button's default text:

```js
<script>
  ...
  let ButtonText = 'CALIBRAR'
  ...
</script>
```

Note that this is obviously valid only for this single calibration button. If you had several buttons with dynamic text, you'd likely have to use an array or keyed object to hold their default value and current state, instead of a single variable.

Answer (score 0):

**I did it as follows:**

```
<script>
  import Button from '../components/Button.svelte'
  import { cubiqSetUp } from '../../../store/store.js'
  import { fly } from 'svelte/transition'
  import URLS from '../../../api/endpoints.js'

  let loadingEffect = [false, false, false, false]
  let ButtonText = ['CUBICAR', 'CALIBRAR', 'GUARDAR', 'IMPRIMIR']
  async function calibrate(current) {
    loadingEffect[1] = true
    ButtonText[1] = 'CARGANDO...'
    let { calibrateURL } = await URLS()
    await fetch(calibrateURL)
      .then(response => {
        loadingEffect[1] = false
        ButtonText[1] = 'LISTO'
        response.json()
        setTimeout(() => {
          ButtonText[1] = current.detail
        }, 1500)
      })
      .catch(error => {
        ButtonText[1] = 'ERROR'
        loadingEffect[1] = false
        setTimeout(() => {
          ButtonText[1] = current.detail
        }, 1500)
      })
  }

  async function cubicate(current) {
    loadingEffect[0] = true
    ButtonText[0] = 'CARGANDO...'
    let { calibrateURL } = await URLS()
    await fetch(calibrateURL)
      .then(response => {
        loadingEffect[0] = false
        ButtonText[0] = 'LISTO'
        response.json()
        setTimeout(() => {
          ButtonText[0] = current.detail
        }, 1500)
      })
      .catch(error => {
        ButtonText[0] = 'ERROR'
        loadingEffect[0] = false
        setTimeout(() => {
          ButtonText[0] = current.detail
        }, 1500)
      })
  }
</script>

<div class="Buttons">
  <div class="Buttons-container">
    <Button
      on:active={cubicate}
      loadingEffect={loadingEffect[0]}
      ButtonText={ButtonText[0]} />
    <Button
      on:active={calibrate}
      loadingEffect={loadingEffect[1]}
      ButtonText={ButtonText[1]}
      delay={400} />
    {#if $cubiqSetUp.print_info === 'true' && $cubiqSetUp.OCR === 'true'}
      <Button
        on:active={() => console.log('Pending')}
        ButtonText={ButtonText[3]}
        loadingEffect={loadingEffect[3]}
        delay={800} />
    {:else if $cubiqSetUp.print_info === 'true'}
      <Button
        on:active={() => console.log('Pending')}
        ButtonText={ButtonText[2]}
        loadingEffect={loadingEffect[2]}
        delay={800} />
      <Button
        on:active={() => console.log('Pending')}
        ButtonText={ButtonText[3]}
        loadingEffect={loadingEffect[3]}
        delay={1200} />
    {:else if $cubiqSetUp.OCR === 'true'}
      <!-- No additional buttons -->
    {:else}
      <Button
        on:active={() => console.log('Pending')}
        ButtonText={ButtonText[2]}
        loadingEffect={loadingEffect[2]}
        delay={800} />
    {/if}
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm not sure if they are the best practices but it works just fine

**Note:** I still need to implement the rest of the functions

Comment: I see a lot of repetition in there, as well as direct access to array indices instead of some form of programmatic loop. I would place all the button related attributes (API sub-route, label, delay, effect) into an array of objects, and write a single function to handle the remote fetching, with the index to the target button as parameter (and you could pass that index in the `detail` of your custom event).

Comment: The rest of the functionalities are different. Even the one whose name is "CUBICAR". I just copy and paste the same "CALIBRAR" func to see is the dispatcher and the effects will work as I wanted to. But thank you for the advice. I will  kept that in mind.